# How to make a dynamic json and get the json response in a jsp in data driven documents

Tags: java, javascript, json, servlets, d3.js

I am new to D3 api.I have to make a tree like structure which  have a json file where the values are hardcoded,and I have a servlet where I am getting some values from database and there I have to make the json dynamically in the servlet and have to set the response back to the D3.This is my html where I have written the d3..I am able to create json using java class but can not call this from the D3.js,This is my java file and the created json and also my html file.....

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // hierarchical data in a flattened list
    String[][] data = {
            {"Toyota", "Gas", "Compact", "Corolla"},
            {"Toyota", "Gas", "Compact", "Camry"},
            {"Toyota", "Hybrid", "Compact", "Prius"},
            {"Honda", "Gas", "Compact", "Civic"}
    };

    TreeManager treeManager = new TreeManager();

    for(String[] row : data)
    {
        // build the path to our items in the tree
        List<String> path = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String item : row)
        {
            // add this item to our path
            path.add(item);
            // will add it unless an Item with this name already exists at this path
            treeManager.addData(treeManager, path);
        }
    }

    treeManager.getData(data[0]).putValue("MPG", 38);
    treeManager.getData(data[1]).putValue("MPG", 28);

    Gson gson = new Gson();

    System.out.println(gson.toJson(treeManager));
}

/**
 * This base class provides the hierarchical property of
 * an object that contains a Map of child objects of the same type.
 * It also has a field - Name
 *
 */
public static abstract class TreeItem implements Iterable<TreeItem>{

    private Map<String, TreeItem> children;     
    private String name;

    public TreeItem() {
        children = new HashMap<String, TreeItem>();
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addChild(String key, TreeItem data) 
    {           
        children.put(key, data);
    }

    public TreeItem getChild(String key) 
    {           
        return children.get(key);
    }

    public boolean hasChild(String key) 
    {           
        return children.containsKey(key);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<TreeItem> iterator() {          
        return children.values().iterator();
    }           
}

/**
 * This is our special case, root node. It is a TreeItem in itself
 * but contains methods for building and retrieving items from our tree
 *
 */
public static class TreeManager extends TreeItem
{       
    /**
     * Will add an Item to the tree at the specified path with the value
     * equal to the last item in the path, unless that Item already exists 
     */
    public void addData(List<String> path)
    {
        addData(this, path);
    }

    private void addData(TreeItem parent, List<String> path)
    {
        // if we're at the end of the path - create a node
        String data = path.get(0);
        if(path.size() == 1)
        {
            // unless there is already a node with this name
            if(!parent.hasChild(data))
            {
                Group group = new Group();
                group.setName(data);
                parent.addChild(data, group);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // pass the tail of this path down to the next level in the hierarchy
            addData(parent.getChild(data), path.subList(1, path.size()));
        }
    }

    public Group getData(String[] path)
    {
        return (Group) getData(this, Arrays.asList(path));
    }

    public Group getData(List<String> path)
    {
        return (Group) getData(this, path);
    }

    private TreeItem getData(TreeItem parent, List<String> path)
    {
        if(parent == null || path.size() == 0)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid path specified in getData, remainder: " 
                    + Arrays.toString(path.toArray()));
        }
        String data = path.get(0);
        if(path.size() == 1)
        {
            return parent.getChild(data);
        }
        else
        {
            // pass the tail of this path down to the next level in the hierarchy
            return getData(parent.getChild(data), path.subList(1, path.size()));
        }
    }
}

public static class Group extends TreeItem {

    private Map<String, Object> properties;

    public Object getValue(Object key) {
        return properties.get(key);
    }

    public Object putValue(String key, Object value) {
        return properties.put(key, value);
    }

    public Group () {
        super();
        properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
       }       
   }


}
```

and this is our json

```
   {
"children": {
    "Toyota": {
        "properties": {},
        "children": {
            "Hybrid": {
                "properties": {},
                "children": {
                    "Compact": {
                        "properties": {},
                        "children": {
                            "Prius": {
                                "properties": {},
                                "children": {},
                                "name": "Prius"
                            }
                        },
                        "name": "Compact"
                    }
                },
                "name": "Hybrid"
            },
            "Gas": {
                "properties": {},
                "children": {
                    "Compact": {
                        "properties": {},
                        "children": {
                            "Corolla": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "MPG": 38
                                },
                                "children": {},
                                "name": "Corolla"
                            },
                            "Camry": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "MPG": 28
                                },
                                "children": {},
                                "name": "Camry"
                            }
                        },
                        "name": "Compact"
                    }
                },
                "name": "Gas"
            }
        },
        "name": "Toyota"
    },
    "Honda": {
        "properties": {},
        "children": {
            "Gas": {
                "properties": {},
                "children": {
                    "Compact": {
                        "properties": {},
                        "children": {
                            "Civic": {
                                "properties": {},
                                "children": {},
                                "name": "Civic"
                            }
                        },
                        "name": "Compact"
                    }
                },
                "name": "Gas"
            }
        },
        "name": "Honda"
           }
         }
     }
```

This is my html  file ...

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

```
.node circle {
    cursor: pointer;
    stroke: #3182bd;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    pointer-events: none;
    text-anchor: middle;
}

line.link {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #9ecae1;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    root;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
    .linkDistance(80)
    .charge(-120)
    .gravity(.04)
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

    //adding as svg element
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

d3.json("graph.json", function(error, json) {
        root = json;
        update(); //responsible for creating the layout
    });

    function update() {
        var nodes = flatten(root),

        /*
         *d3.layout.tree() is the starting point 
         *for tree layouts in D3. 
         *The call to this function returns an object
         * that contains a bunch of methods to configure 
         * the layout and also provides methods to 
         * compute the layout
         **/           

        links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);//attach the nodes

        // Restart the force layout.
        force
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .start();

        // Update links.
        link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

        link.exit().remove();

        link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
        .attr("class", "link");

        // Update nodes.
        node = node.data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });

        node.exit().remove();

        var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .on("click", click)
        .call(force.drag);

        nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; });

        nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

        node.select("circle")
        .style("fill", color);
    }


    /*Giving elements on click*/
    function tick() {
        link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
    }


    /*Adjusting the color of each node*/
    function color(d) {
        return d._children ? "#3182bd" // collapsed package
        : d.children ? "#c6dbef" // expanded package
        : "#fd8d3c"; // leaf node
    }

    // Toggle children on click.
    function click(d) {
        if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // ignore drag
        if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d.children = null;
        } else {
            d.children = d._children;
            d._children = null;
        }
        update();
    }

    // Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
    function flatten(root) {
        var nodes = [], i = 0;

        function recurse(node) {
            if (node.children) node.children.forEach(recurse);
            if (!node.id) node.id = ++i;
            nodes.push(node);
        }

        recurse(root);
        return nodes;
    }

</script>
```

this is the json and the html file, now I have to make the json dynamically and set the response back
to the D3 api.Anyone please help...

Comment: i have to call this from my D3.js someone plesae help

Answer (score 0):

This code is retrieving the JSON file from your server using an AJAX request:

```
d3.json("graph.json", function(error, json) {
    root = json;
    update(); //responsible for creating the layout
});
```

Right now the URL you're using will simply grab a static file named "graph.json" from the same location as the HTML file on the server.  You can change this URL to one that invokes `doGet` in your servlet and then make `doGet` return the dynamic JSON you want.

Comment: i am able to make json dynamically with java,the json which is forming is also tree structure.but i can not call that json class from my D3.js.am posting  my Java class and the generated json.

Comment: Why can't you invoke the servlet from your JS?  The `doGet` method in a servlet is invoked via URL.  `d3.json` takes a URL as the first argument.  Am I missing something?

Comment: d3.json("ActionServlet", function(error, json) {
        root = json;
        update(); //responsible for creating the layout
    });
m doing this but the output is not coming ..am I doing  write??

Comment: If you replace the HTML file name in your browser URL with "ActionServlet" do you get a bunch of JSON back? That would be the first thing to check.

Comment: If your HTML file is http://host/myfile.html and opening http://host/ActionServlet in your browser results in JSON being returned, then the code you have (`d3.json("ActionServlet", function()...)`) should work.  `d3.json` will do an HTTP GET to the relative URL specified in the first argument.

Comment: {"name":{"Toyota":{"properties":{"MPG":38},"name":{},"children":"Toyota"},"Camry":{"properties":{},"name":{},"children":"Camry"}}}//this is the json I have dynamically crated can you help me with a d3.js script that will fit this json and will show a tree like structure???